# rewrite ` Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` showing error `Select' not found`

Tags: magento2, collection, overrides, catalog

I am trying to override the class `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`

On overwrite class, i got the error

> Fatal error: Class
>   'AmitBera\CoreRewrite\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\ResourceModel\Product\Select'
>   not found in
>   /var/www/html/magento215sample/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php
>   on line 333

I  have tried to call `$this->getSelect()` at a ***function of overwrite class***

```
<?php
namespace AmitBera\CoreRewrite\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\ResourceModel\Product;

class Collection extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
{

    protected $appState;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\State $catalogProductFlatState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $productOptionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url $catalogUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
                $entityFactory,
                $logger,
                $fetchStrategy,
                $eventManager,
                $eavConfig,
                $resource,
                $eavEntityFactory,
                $resourceHelper,
                $universalFactory,
                $storeManager,
                $moduleManager,
                $catalogProductFlatState,
                $scopeConfig,
                $productOptionFactory,
                $catalogUrl,
                $localeDate,
                $customerSession,
                $dateTime,
                $groupManagement,
                $connection
            );
        $this->_appState = $appState;

    }


   public function setOrder($attribute, $dir = Select::SQL_DESC)
   {

    /* gettign the error at getSelect() */
    echo $this->getSelect()->__toString();
    exit;

    if ($attribute == 'sort_by_stocks'){
            $select =$this->getSelect();
            $select->joinLeft(
                array('stock_qty' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
                'e.entity_id = stock_qty.product_id AND stock_qty.website_id='.$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsite()->getId(),
                array(
                    'salable' => 'stock_qty.stock_status',
                    'qty' => 'stock_qty.qty'
                )
            );

            $reverseDir = ($dir == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
            //this is optional - it shows the in stock products above the out of stock ones independent if sorting by position ascending or descending
           $this->getSelect()->order('salable DESC');

            return $this;
     }else{
        return parent::setOrder($attribute,$dir);   
     } 

   }
}
```

### Question:

Why i am getting the error 'Select' not found when call at `$this->getSelect()`  but at parent class  `$this->getSelect()`exits but At rewrite class **why we are not able to call** on rewrite class`

Comment: It should work. But can you try this `$this->getSelectSql();` and check if thats working. Because both are coming from `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb`.

Comment: Also there might be something related to this class `Magento\Framework\DB\Select;` which is actually used to return the data `getSelect();` inside `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb` and also used inside `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`;

Comment: yes. kingshuk  this getSelect should works.I have found my issue  in setOrder() function  parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my  mistake.

Issue was in parameter of `setOrder()`.

**Select**  class codes does not found at rewrite class but i  was send  it constant variable at  `Select::SQL_DESC` at `setOrder()`.

I have changes `Select` to   `\Magento\Framework\DB\Select` and it is working

Comment: Are you able to overwrite the collection methods? Actually I use the same code in Magento230, construct method is working fine but methods are not overridden. Any Idea?